# Java ant Eclipse run error

Tags: java, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ant error JAVA_HOME does not point to SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285301/ant-error-java-home-does-not-point-to-sdk)

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> BUILD FAILED
> C:\Users\myname\Documents\CMSC\Proj1\build.xml:22: Unable to find a javac compiler;
> com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
> It is currently set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
>
> Total time: 1 second
> ```

My build.xml file contains the following code:

```
<project name="Project1" default="compile" basedir=".">

  <description>
    Build file for Project1
  </description>

  <!-- global properties for this build file -->
  <property name="source.dir" location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin"/>
  <property name="doc.dir" location="doc"/>
  <property name="main.class" value="proj1.Project1"/>

  <!-- set up some directories used by this project -->
  <target name="init" description="setup project directories">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <!-- Compile the java code in ${src.dir} into ${build.dir} -->
  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile java sources">
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <!-- execute the program with the fully qualified name in ${build.dir} -->
  <target name="run" description="run the project">
    <java dir="${build.dir}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <!-- Delete the build & doc directories and Emacs backup (*~) files -->
  <target name="clean" description="tidy up the workspace">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <delete>
      <fileset defaultexcludes="no" dir="${source.dir}" includes="**/*~"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <!-- Generate javadocs for current project into ${doc.dir} -->
  <target name="doc" depends="init" description="generate documentation">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

What am I doing wrong here? It appears that it's trying to find a javac file in my src folder but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Jre and jdk are different things, you know.

Comment: @martinclayton Not really a duplicate as the guy is running the ant script using Eclipse. The environment configuration is slightly different to the configuration while running it from a command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` must be pointed to `JDK` and not `JRE`.

To test it, before executing `ant` type `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07` or whatever version you have.

Comment: I'm running this from inside eclipse. To change it to the location of the JDK, do I have to modify eclipse's settings or the build file?

Comment: It's more of a shell setting. But Eclipse can invoke shells. There is a section for installed JDKs and JRE's. You need to be using the JDK. It has the binaries for things like, javac in it.

Comment: Try adding your `JDK` to Eclipse by using `Window`->`Preferences`->`Java`->`Installed JREs`. Click the button `Add...` and then set the JDK to the default JRE.

Answer (score 4):

Download the latest JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html).  Install it and notice where it goes.  For example, the 32-bit JDK should install to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkSOMETHING`.

In Eclipse, go to `Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Installed JREs` and click `Add` > `Standard JVM` (then `Next`).  Browse to the directory noted above for the JDK and then hit `Finish`.  To check that your project is using this JDK, right-click the project and go to `Properties`.  From there, look for `Java Build Path`.  Under the `Libraries` tab you should see a `JRE System Library`.  If it's not the JDK you just added, click the entry and hit the `Edit` button and change it.

Now run your `Ant` build.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error, looks like its Windows environment and you are running `ant` through command prompt.

```
Follow Right Click(My Computer) -> properties -> Advanced 
-> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New
Add  Variable Name = JAVA_HOME
     Variable Value = Path to your Base folder of Java 
                      e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxx
```

Restart the command prompt, type `java -version`. If it prints your java version correctly, you should be all set.

Answer (score -1):

it is saying

> "Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK."

Perhaps you should check that :D

Comment: I'm new to this and I'm using eclipse. Should I change eclipse's settings or the build file?

Comment: try searching for something like this "how to run ant from eclipse" in Google and follow the instructions.