# JAVA_HOME not pointed at JDK

Tags: java, android, windows, ant, automation

I know that this question has been asked several times, but none of the answers seem to have worked.

**Short version:**
I need to get Ant to point to my JDK rather than my JRE.

**Long version:**

My issue is that I'm trying to do some `Android` automation, and I am using a `Powershell` script to kick this off. Once the Powershell script runs, JUnit tests are run via an Ant build. But when I build I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:598: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:713: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:727: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Android\Jre7"
```

I thought the problem might be that I didn't set the JAVA_HOME variable correctly, so I checked:

Here is the output of my JAVA_HOME run from my command line:

```
C:\Android\JDK
```

Here is the output when I run `set` in command line:

```
C:\Android\JDK
```

Here is the output when I run `$env:$JAVA_HOME` from the Powershell command line

```
C:\Android\JDK
```

Everywhere I look, it seems that the `JAVA_HOME` path is set to:

```
C:\Android\JDK
```

I have also tried to update the `build.xml` file in Android, but that didn't work. I looked at the `ant.bat` file, but that didn't help. I'm really at a loss on this.

Here is my PATH:

```
PATH=C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Fil
es\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\
windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Android\JDK\bin;C:\Android\apache-ant-1.9.1\bin;C:\Android\android-ndk-r8e;C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools;C\perl\x86\bin;C:\Android\JDK\bin;
```

Here is a list of the links I have looked at and tried:

[Java ant Eclipse run error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806700/java-ant-eclipse-run-error)

[Ant build not working: unable to find a javac compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930181/ant-build-not-working-unable-to-find-a-javac-compiler)

[Java ant Eclipse run error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806700/java-ant-eclipse-run-error)

[Why does ANT tell me that JAVA_HOME is wrong when it is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558780/why-does-ant-tell-me-that-java-home-is-wrong-when-it-is-not)

I'm sure there are a couple more, but I can't remember everything I've tried, but I've spent a couple hours on this now.

I am running Windows 8, on a Dell PC. I have JDK 7 installed, along with the Android Eclipse and SDK. I am using Ant 1.9.1

If I left anything out, I'm sorry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know the JRE is not a JDK, I'm trying to get it to recognize my JDK and I need to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my issue, I ended up having to uninstall & reinstall the JDK, making sure NOT to install the JRE that is included with the JDK (the second version, the 'stand-alone' JRE, not the JRE included IN the JDK).

I also had to reinstall Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the system environment variable:

```
setx JAVA_HOME C:\Android\JDK
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Thank you for the response though.